# CSS: Reduce element size on hover, but keep original "hover area"

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to reduce element size a bit as an effect, when it is hovered over with a mouse. However, this looks buggy because as the element reduces in size, the "hover area" gets smaller as well, which can result into the element not being hovered anymore, which further results into this "size flickering".

Is there a proper way to implement element size reduction on hover, while keeping the hover area size the same? Without extra elements?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/88f5by59/

Required code for fiddle linking:

```
#di
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di:hover
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

Comment: We need to see exaclty how is this *element*. Please provide some code.

Comment: No...not without another element to maintain the hover. I'd probably go with  awrapping element. or javascript.

Comment: Wrap the element in a DIV and put the hover on THAT.  You can change whatever element you want when the hover triggers.  You can change an object on the other side of the screen if you want.

Comment: @LcSalazar Added a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping it in a div would be better, as commented. But if adding no other elements is a **must**, you could work with pseudo elements.

Make the visible part a pseudo element (like `:before`), and keep the main one just for hovering:

*TIP: If you want the transition effect on both mouse over and out, set the property to the main css rule, not to the hover one*

```css
#di
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di:hover:before
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div id = "di">
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried to solution durbpoisn suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/505d0eat/ I like this pseudo element solution even more!

Comment: Can pseudo element be used, if the hovered element is not a rectangle, but instead like some svg element such as a svg path?

Comment: Yes, a pseudo will act as any other element, you can use all css properties in it

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the div inside a container and "bind" the hover event to the parent.

P.S obviously it is a solution with adding other elements.

```css
#container
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container, #di{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di{
  background-color: #2980b9;

}


#container:hover #di
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="di">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is your answer. You have to add one more element. See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vwy4utf5/

html:

```
<div id = "di">
<div id="diin">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #di{width:101px; height:101px; cursor:pointer; position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;}

    #diin
    {

      background-color: #2980b9;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
       transition: all 200ms linear;
    }

#di:hover > div
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using Jquery, didn't specified by OP but I guess it can help somebody.

So changed css to make parent positioning of new parent:

```
#di {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di_parent {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}


#di_parent:hover > DIV {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

Then added some JQuery to create a container to each object to maitain size as is suggested above.

```
$('#di').each(function(i, v){
    var o, p;
  o=$(v);
  p=$('<div id="di_parent"></div>');
  p.css({height:o.outerHeight(),width:o.outerWidth()});
  o.after(p); 
  p.append(o.detach());
});
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/88f5by59/11/

```js
$('#di').each(function(i, v){
 var o, p;
  o=$(v);
  p=$('<div id="di_parent"></div>');
  p.css({height:o.outerHeight(),width:o.outerWidth()});
  o.after(p); 
  p.append(o.detach());
});
```

```css
#di {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#di_parent {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}


#di_parent:hover > DIV {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "di">
</div>
```

Hope it helps!